# Error when update in table oracle using spring

Tags: spring, oracle

here I try to make spring and connect it to oracle DB. I make an update query that update a lot of data. before this error appear, I also faced error connection pool are in used. here some error log that I faced right now

```
2023-Jul-05 16:14:24,965|[jobDynamicExecutionScheduler_Worker-8]|org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger||ERROR|Job (DEFAULT.jobBulkBATCH20230705160503230705161408984b6d1469d threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'controllingBroadcastRequest' on target class [class com.*.*.*] failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
```

before this error appeared, the error that appeared before was connection are in used, but that error was gone when I added it

```
<property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="80" />
<property name="TimeToLiveConnectionTimeout" value="10" />
```

in the config database.xml on spring. any help is very helpful. thank you

Comment: `java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation` Increase the timeout value to something greater than the maximum (or typical) duration that you expect the request to take.

Comment: This error occurs purely from the oracle database side sir ?

Comment: What appears to be happening is that Spring will start the job, it will execute until it gets to the timeout and then Spring will tell that database to cancel the job (as it has taken too long) and then the database receives the notification and raises an exception `ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation` to stop the job. While the exception is coming from the database, I would argue that all the control is happening in Spring and that is where you need to make the changes to stop it cancelling the job.

Comment: it means the TimeToLiveConnectionTimeout function is what I have to enlarge, so I can wait longer or do you have other options so spring don't stop the query process ? My goal is that get the result although it takes a long time